# Shapes overlapped in pre-comp, transparent fade in visibility

Tags: after-effects

I have two white shapes that overlap on a purple background, which are in a pre-comp. One in animated (an arm) and the other is not (the rest of the body).

When I fade the pre-comp in, from 0 to 100 opacity, I can see the parts where the shape overlaps. This is made worse by having a motion blur, which seems to multiply the blur in that area.

[image]

Do you know how to avoid this situation, and to have the two shapes behave as one.

Comment: Are you fading in the parts of the pre-comp or are you actually using the pre-comp in another composition and fading in the entire pre-comp? This appears to be the result of a blending issue since if you aren't using a separate comp, you end up with two objects being blended at 50% but behind one object at 50% is another object at 50% which blocks out more than 50% of the background, thus you see the difference.

Comment: The body and arm are two shapes in a pre-comp. Then the pre-comp itself has the opacity change animation on it.

Comment: Hmm, no idea then.  The issue is definitely blending related, but I'm not sure the best way to fix.  It is treating it as 2 50% solids instead of 1 combined solid that is at 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is due to the little sun icon - the "collapse transformations" icon.. 
See more here: http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/3d-layers.html

It's to do with what order 3D comp layers are processed when they're precomped.

Comment: Yes, that worked thank you. I wrapped the pre-comp inside another pre-comp and collapsed transformations on the top two layers of pre-comp. People (waving animation) > People Wrap (Nothing going on here) > Icon People (Collapse transformations) > Main Comp (Collapse transformations).